# i want to user collection to change special characters one by one in my code

Tags: oracle, plsql

i want to change special characters dynamically one by one in my below given code by using varray collection or any way . please modify my code to check all the special characters one by one in table. for-example--->> just want to replace & in my code with # dynamically.

```
DECLARE
table_or_view_does_not_exist exception;
pragma exception_init(table_or_view_does_not_exist,-00942);
d_table varchar2(200);
q_table varchar2(200);
  v_sql   VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_value VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_cur   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN  
DBMS_OUTPUT. ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);
begin
d_table:='drop table fms_addr_Spcl_Char PURGE';
execute immediate d_table;
exception
when table_or_view_does_not_exist then
null;
end;
----dbms_output.put_line('Table has been dropped');
q_table:='create table fms_addr_Spcl_Char 
         (table_name varchar2(50), 
         column_name varchar2(50),
         spcl_char varchar2(500),
         spcl_char_count varchar2(50))';
         execute immediate q_table;
---dbms_output.put_line('Table has been created');
  FOR r IN (
    select table_name,
           column_name
    from   all_tab_columns
    where  table_name=upper('fms_user_address_book')
    and    OWNER = 'FMS_ADMIN'
  ) loop
    v_sql := 'select "'||r.column_name||'" AS data
              from   "'||r.table_name||'"
              where  regexp_like ("'||r.column_name||'",''[&]'') and zone=''SZ''';
    -------DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_sql);
OPEN v_cur FOR v_sql;
    LOOP
      FETCH v_cur INTO v_value;
      EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;
    --------DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.table_name || '.' || r.column_name  || '---->' || v_value||'  '||v_cur%rowcount);
    null;
   END LOOP;
   if v_cur%rowcount<>0 then
    execute immediate 'insert into fms_addr_Spcl_Char values (:param1,:param2,:param3,:param4)' 
    using r.table_name,r.column_name ,'&',v_cur%rowcount;
    end if;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large data set, then

- one-by-one character substitution is probably not very efficient
- regular expressions are *nice*, but also probably not very efficient

Though, you have to sacrifice *something*, so I'll try to make it simple.

This is your *log* table, slightly modified (I don't care which characters were substituted; NUMBER of substitutions should be exactly that - a *number*, not *varchar2*):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE fms_addr_Spcl_Char
  2  (
  3     table_name        VARCHAR2 (50),
  4     column_name       VARCHAR2 (50),
  5     spcl_char_count   NUMBER
  6  );

Table created.
```

Sample table: 3 substitutions are expected in `NAME`, 2 in `ADDRESS` column:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM test
  3  ORDER BY id;

        ID NAME          ADDRESS
---------- ------------- -------------
         1 Little        Big City %1
         2 Fo&ot         This Avenue 2
         3 S!?P          Elm street
         4 Th!s i$ wr?ng Lon$don
```

Let's do it; I wouldn't create log table dynamically. There are really rare situations where you have to do that, and this is not one of them. Create table in advance, work with it in your PL/SQL procedure.

Procedure updates columns that contain "special characters" - you didn't say which ones you call "special", so I'm replacing everything that's not letter, digit or space. Number of replacements is stored into the log table:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_str  VARCHAR2 (1000);
  3     l_cnt  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     DELETE FROM fms_addr_Spcl_Char;
  6
  7     FOR cur_r IN (SELECT table_name, column_name
  8                     FROM user_Tab_columns
  9                    WHERE     table_name = 'TEST'
 10                          AND data_type LIKE '%CHAR%')
 11     LOOP
 12        l_str :=
 13              'update '
 14           || cur_r.table_name
 15           || ' set '
 16           || cur_r.column_name
 17           || ' = regexp_replace('
 18           || cur_r.column_name
 19           || q'{, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', '#')}'
 20           || ' where regexp_like('
 21           || cur_r.column_name
 22           || q'{, '[^A-Za-z0-9 ]')}';
 23
 24        -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_str);
 25        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str;
 26
 27        l_cnt := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
 28
 29        IF SQL%ROWCOUNT > 0
 30        THEN
 31           INSERT INTO fms_addr_Spcl_Char
 32                VALUES (cur_r.table_name, cur_r.column_name, l_cnt);
 33        END IF;
 34     END LOOP;
 35  END;
 36  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL>   SELECT *
  2      FROM test
  3  ORDER BY id;

        ID NAME          ADDRESS
---------- ------------- -------------
         1 Little        Big City #1
         2 Fo#ot         This Avenue 2
         3 S##P          Elm street
         4 Th#s i# wr#ng Lon#don
```

Log table contents:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM fms_addr_spcl_char;

TABLE_NAME           COLUMN_NAME          SPCL_CHAR_COUNT
-------------------- -------------------- ---------------
TEST                 NAME                               3
TEST                 ADDRESS                            2

SQL>
```